# when i run entry.js and I createStore,but l have a warning Invalid prop `store` of type `function` supplied to `Provider`, expected `object`

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

enrty.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {createStore,applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import reducer from './reducers/index';

import Add from './containers/add';
import AddRequest from './middlewares/add';

const createStoreMiddle = applyMiddleware(AddRequest);
const Store = createStoreMiddle(reducer);

render(
   <Provider store={Store}>
    <Add />
   </Provider>,document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Unfortunately, it complains with:

```
//warning.js?8a56:36 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `store` of type `function` supplied to `Provider`, expected `object`.in Provider
//connectAdvanced.js?a26c:35 Uncaught TypeError: store.getState is not a function
```

I search so many but can't resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use `createStore`, you need to write it like this:

```
const createStoreMiddle = applyMiddleware(AddRequest);

const Store = createStore(reducer, createStoreMiddle); // use createStore

render(
   <Provider store={Store}>
      <Add />
   </Provider>,document.getElementById('app')
);
```

[Check this for more detail](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html#example-using-thunk-middleware-for-async-actions)